# Covariation for Wiener process squared

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

$W = \{W_t, t \geq 0\}$ is a Wiener process. Task is to find the covariation function of $X_t = W_t^2$.

My thoughts were to apply the following standard trick:
$cov(X_s, X_t) = cov((W_s - W_t)^2, W_s^2) + 2cov(W_tW_s, W_s^2) - cov(W_s^2, W_s^2) = 2cov(W_tW_s, W_s^2) - DW_s^2$
But here $cov(W_tW_s, W_s^2)$ seems hard to calculate.

Pls help.

Comment: Which part is difficult? $E(W_tW_s^3)$? $E(W_tW_s)$? $E(W_s^2)$?

Comment: $E(W_tW_s^3)$ :(

Comment: Why? You already know the trick of decomposing $W_t$ into $(W_t-W_s)+W_s$, right?

Comment: Aw, right!
It opened my eyes :)

Comment: ...Not enough to prevent you from accepting an answer pretending that $E(W_s^4)$ should scale like $s^4$, it seems, which is absurd.